# Ionic2 SearchBar confusion, onInput called after firing onClear, onCancel

Tags: ionic2

I have been following the tutorial at [ionic2 SearchBar](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#searchbar) to work on the filter functionality.

The question is, I am not able to figure out how to get onCancel and onClear to work.

Steps:
1) Enter some keywords in SearchBar. It calls the onInput event and I get the value from **searchItem.target.value** unlike in tutorial which just uses *searchItem.value*

2) Now i try to click on clear "x" or Cancel button and it calls the onClear/onCancel event which is immediately followed by onInput event. And during this call, it does not find the **searchItem.target.value** and results in **undefined** due to which it breaks the functionality.

Can anyone provide more in depth details on how this works?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it in tutorial sample for ionic2 by stopping onClear event propagation

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-search',
        template: '<ion-toolbar primary><ion-searchbar (input)="onInput($event)" (ionClear)="onClear($event)"></ion-searchbar></ion-toolbar><ion-content><ion-list><ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item }}</ion-item></ion-list></ion-content>'
    })
    export class HomePage {

        items = [];

        constructor() {
            this.initializeItems();
        }

        initializeItems() {
            this.items = [
                'Angular 1.x',
                'Angular 2',
                'ReactJS',
                'EmberJS',
                'Meteor',
                'Typescript',
                'Dart',
                'CoffeeScript'
            ];
        }

        onClear(ev)
        {
            this.initializeItems();
            ev.stopPropagation();
        }

        onInput(ev) {
            // Reset items back to all of the items
            this.initializeItems();

            // set val to the value of the searchbar
            var val = ev.target.value;

            // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
            if (val && val.trim() != '') {
                this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
                    return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
                })
            }
        }
    }
```